# IF Statement with two expressions

Tags: java, if-statement

Sorry I'm still new at java but I just needed help with the if statement

here's my code:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
answer = keyboard.next();

if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
{
   System.out.println ("ur answer is: " + answer);
}
```

I want that if I type "y" it should work also, 
So i tried This :

```
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"||"y")    
{
   System.out.println ("ur answer is: " + answer);
}
```

but it's not working

Comment: Try `if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`

Comment: It will be `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")`.

Answer (score -1):

You're close. Try:

```
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

Comment: Thank You , that worked